# How can I display a list view (multi level) in an Android activity dialog

Tags: android, listview, include

include activity in dialog...activity include multi list view
please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I see, this is not an activity in a dialog. The Dialog itself has custom view which has title, edit text and list view.

Not sure what are u looking for....but you can create a CustomDialog like this:

custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parrent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your activity create it like:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");
```